# ECharts generated label overlaps with dataZoom

Tags: echarts

Using ECharts I am giving it a data series that consists of a number of data against really values. (e.g plotting stock prices).

I also have data zoom enabled.

My issue is that the generated X axis' labels overlap with the dataZoom. I can't understand from the documentation how to fix this.

[image: x Axis label overlap issues]

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the value of `grid.bottom`. This will move the whole grid further from the bottom of the canvas and pull the whole *X Axis* with it.

Example: `grid: { bottom: 60 }`

```
// usage
this._displayedChart.setOption({ grid: { bottom: 10 } })
```

Not a great solution but works.

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#grid.bottom